# How do I backup a website with a Wordpress frontend and a Magento 1.7 backend and be able to use it as a local server?

Tags: magento, xampp, web-hosting

I'm backing up my old website to a local server. I've placed the backup folder in htdocs in xampp, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I've tried importing the SQL tables, but received a formatting error. I've tried going to the files in the folder via web browser but got redirected to the live site.

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress and magento you have to run following queries as below

**Wordpress**

```
UPDATE  wp_options SET option_value = "localhost url" WHERE option_name = "siteurl"
UPDATE  wp_options SET option_value = "localhost url" WHERE option_name = "home"
```

**Magento**

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'localhost url' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'localhost url' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';
```